# how to create a c function of `numpy.array`?

Tags: python, c, numpy, scipy, package

I was looking at this tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html
and understood how to write `c` functions of scalar arguments (which return, say, a `double`) and *broadcastable* functions that accept as argument `numpy.array`s and return another `numpy.array` by default.

How can I write a `c` function that takes one or more `numpy.array`s and return a scalar value, instead?

Comment: I would recommend using Cython. See here: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Comment: I make pure C dll for Python. To pass `numpy.ndarray` for the `void func(int*px);` of  `C` dll in Python, I use the pointer: `x = np.arange(10);px=x.ctypes.data`.

Comment: thanks! Watch about performances? Would a well written cython package be as fast as the pure c one? @Silencer Where is documented the ctype for np.array?

Comment: @altroware Cython is another language for me. I just write pure python with pure c code, and for now it's no need for me to use Cython. I learned this in a QQ group. It works well, so I have not search for document. You may google `numpy ctypes` for some links.

Answer (score 0):

To write a new Python function (generally) in C, see:  https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

And here is page with an example function (addList) to use as a starting point:  http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/python_c_extension.html#python-c-api

Then, to access function arguments that are numpy arrays, see the Numpy C-API documentation, here:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#array-structure-and-data-access

Comment: But, How can I pass a ‘numpy.array’?